# Expectation of the binomial distribution, where the number of trials is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose

- $Y_1 \sim Binomial(X_1,\delta)$
- $Y_2 \sim Binomial(X_2,\delta)$
- $X_1>0$ and $X_2>0$ are random variables
- $E[X_1]>E[X_2]$

Then does the following hold? $E[Y_1]>E[Y_2]$

Comment: do you have any idea about the question?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks for the comment. Intuitively, I think $E[Y_1]>E[Y_2]$ because, on average, the number of trials is greater for $Y_1$ than $Y_2$.

Comment: Perhaps considering $E[Y_{1}]=E[E(Y_{1}|X_{1})]$ will give you some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of iterated expectation, we have $$E[Y_i]=E[E[Y_i|X_i]]=\delta E[X_i]$$

Since $E[X_1] > E[X_2]$, if $\delta >0$, we have

$$\delta E[X_1] > \delta E[X_2]$$

Hence $E[Y_1]> E[Y_2]$.